# Does the Xcode `Archive` function automatically use the `Release` build configuration?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

My standard workflow, when releasing an app to the App Store, is to press `Product > Archive` from Xcode's menubar.

I realize that I never change the Xcode `Build Configuration` in my build scheme. I have it set to `Debug` during development, but want the version on the App Store to be `Release`.

I am hoping and assuming that `Product > Archive` automatically uses a `Release` build configuration. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Yes. By default, the Debug configuration is used for running on the Simulator while the Release is for Archives. I recommend looking at your Schemes.

> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme...

Comment: Ah, perfect. Did not see that Archive was listed in `Edit Scheme...` you are able to switch it to Debug, even, but Release is the default.

Comment: cksubs, thanks for your comment. It was what I was looking for

Comment: But i am still confused. What if i manually choose the debug version(for debuggind and don't remember to change it back to release) and archive it and put it on test flight. Would it still upload the debug version or will it automatically switch to release build?

Comment: It will still upload the debug version unfortunately. I am going through this currently and I just got off the phone with Apple dev support to have my build switched to a different release build before the debug build goes out.

Answer (score 7):

**Xcode Scheme, Action, Build configuration**

```
Target -> Schema -> Action -> Build configuration
```

[[Scheme]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877)

**actions**: run, test, profile, analyze, archive

`Build Configuration`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266553/4770877): Debug, Release,

To check/change `Build Configuration` you should edit/manage schema

[image]

To find `Archive action`:

```
<target_name> -> Edit Scheme... -> Archive
//or
<target_name> -> Manage Schemes... -> <target_name> -> Archive
```

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't actually describe how to get to the screenshotted window, unlike Ben M's answer, which is shorter and leads directly to it.

Comment: @TylerForsythe, the question was `I am hoping and assuming that Product > Archive automatically uses a Release build configuration. Can anyone confirm?` And my answer contains a screenshot which proves there.